# "Désolé de ne pas avoir été présent" et "y"

Tags: prépositions, y

> Désolé de ne pas avoir été présent à ta soutenance.

Je me demande où il faut mettre "y" pour remplacer à ta soutenance.

> Désolé de n'y pas avoir été présent.

Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il existe trois façons de placer les mots de cette combinaison; on voit à partir d'un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+n%27y+pas+avoir%2Cde+ne+pas+y+avoir%2Cde+n%27y+avoir+pas&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20n%27y%20pas%20avoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20ne%20pas%20y%20avoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20n%27y%20avoir%20pas%3B%2Cc0) que « **de n'y avoir pas été** » et « **de ne pas y avoir été** » sont courantes et que « **de n'y pas avoir été** » est rare.

Il ne faut cependant pas déduire à partir d'une fréquence d'utilisation qu'une forme donnée est idéale parce que c'est la plus utilisée, ce n'est pas nécessairement faire justice à une forme; cela peut être le cas mais il n'y a pas de règle. Ce que l'on appelle le langage recherché est évidemment utilisé par beaucoup moins de monde mais cela n'en fait pas un langage inférieur, c'est tout le contraire; le langage recherché est un idéal vers lequel un utilisateur averti cherche toujours à tendre. Il ne faut pas non plus tomber dans l'erreur que « rare » signifie « recherché ».

Dans le cas présent des trois possibilités existantes, je ne vois pas pourquoi utiliser l'une plutôt que l'autre : toutes sont correctes. C'est pour cela que bien qu'au début il faille se laisser guider par le gout général, petit à petit il faut s'en remettre à son gout personnel, qui ne peut que se développer, et faire ses propres choix lorsque l'on peut reconnaitre qu'il s'agit de gout personnel.

Pour finir, disons que si « Désolé de n'y pas avoir été présent. » vous plait, il n'y a aucune raison de laisser qui que ce soit vous imposer autre chose.

Answer (score 2):

> Désolé de ne pas y avoir été présent.

Comment: Merci. C'est bon (et très rapide:-)!)